# Why the Ajax responses are getting mixed up in this case

Tags: jquery

When I click on `prev` button, I have the following call:

```
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event ) {
    var query=  fecthDocumentData(document_id_prev,'prev');
    query.done(function() {
        $("#BrandNames").trigger('change');
    });
});
```

Which actually triggers an event on a drop down box:

```
$("select#BrandNames").change(function() {
    showT1(vendor_brand_id, '');
});

function showT1(vendor_brand_id, t1categorytext) {
    if(vendor_brand_id)
    {
        var ajaxq = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + '/OMS/admin/categorylevelservice?vendor_brand_id=' + vendor_brand_id + '&reqstr=' + t1categorytext,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#T1').html('<img src="input-spinner.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                displayT1(response, t1categorytext)
            },
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code for fecthdocument

```
function fecthDocumentData(document_id, btnname)
{

return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/admin/document?document_row=' + document_id + '&btnName=' + btnname,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
         var res = response;
         var document_id_loc = res.data.document_id;


           if(document_id_loc)
           {

}

}
```

The problem I am facing is that the two ajax responses are getting mixed up.

Could anybody please let me know how to resolve this??

Comment: `fetchDocumentData` -- misspelled?

Comment: What two AJAX requests?

Comment: Is there more code to this, I'm only seeing one ajax call?

Comment: yes fetchDocumentData  is a one more ajax call .

Comment: so what do you mean by 'mixed up'? you trigger two ajax calls, do you mean the order they return?

Comment: `getting mixed up` isn't a proper problem statement

Comment: yes exactly i want to do  $("#BrandNames").trigger('change'); ony when the fecthdocument is completely done.

Comment: Does `fecthDocumentData` return a promise? Need to see that code

Comment: @charlietfl i have copied code of fecthdocument in my question .

Comment: Still not clear what your problem is. My guess is your variable assignments are causing problems